# include native lib into CRNA app

Tags: react-native, redux-thunk, native-base, react-native-maps, create-react-native-app

Hi I am tried to work with React Native Map components with my application created by CRNA. so it is possible to include React Native Map components and work with API like MapView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Expo SDK included in CNRA. And, fortunately, React Native Map is in the package : https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view.html

So, you have just to import MapView from expo and play with it!

If you want to use other native librairies not included in the Expo package, you can eject your application: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md